# :not(:first-child) and :not(:first-of-type) not working

Tags: html, css

I have sort of a tree system. What I'm trying to do is give all the parents a margin except for the first one. This is my HTML:

```
<div id="someDivID">
    <div class="theBody">
        <div class="someContainer">
            <div id="someItem" class="someItemClass">
                Test
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="someContainer">
            <div id="someItem2" class="someItemClass">
                Test2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#someDivID
{
    width: 400px;
}

#someItem,
#someItem2
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
}

.someItemClass
{
    background-color: #0077FF;
}

.someItemClass:not(:first-of-type)
{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Now, my `.someContainer` has got the background color but the 2nd `.someContainer` doesn't have a top margin. If I remove the `:first-of-type` it works. `:first-child` doesn't work either.

Here's my jsfiddles:

With `first-of-type`: http://jsfiddle.net/JoshB1997/zsu2o3cg/

With `first-child`: http://jsfiddle.net/JoshB1997/zsu2o3cg/1/

Answer (score 120, accepted):

That's because they are not siblings.

If you change the :not selector to the parent div, it will work.

```
.someContainer:not(:first-of-type)
{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```css
#someDivID
{
    width: 400px;
}

#someItem,
#someItem2
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
}

.someContainer
{
    background-color: #0077FF;
}

.someContainer:not(:first-of-type)
{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="someDivID">
    <div class="theBody">
        <div class="someContainer">
            <div id="someItem" class="someItemClass">
                Test
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="someContainer">
            <div id="someItem2" class="someItemClass">
                Test2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that this simply won't work:

```css
#someDivID
{
    width: 400px;
}

#someItem,
#someItem2
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
}

.someContainer
{
    background-color: #0077FF;
}

.someContainer:not(:first-of-type)
{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="someDivID">
    <div class="theBody">
       <div class=other>Other class element won't work.</div>
        <div class="someContainer">
            <div id="someItem" class="someItemClass">
                Test
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="someContainer">
            <div id="someItem2" class="someItemClass">
                Test2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's good, it works on my example code. But my main code is much more complex and it doesn't simply work. I will just try somethings out but this certainly helps. Thanks for the help. - Edit: it works now correctly!

Comment: Does not really work. The real test is putting another element before any .someContainer. Issue is it will act like last-child pretty much, at least with a class selector.

Answer (score 4):

As Edd above me suggested, they are not siblings - so you need to change your selector to the parent (`.someContainer`).

But I'd also suggest another approach, the "positive" approach - set the first child of a selector to not have the wanted properties and **all the rest to have it**

```
.someContainer:first-child {
    margin-top: 0
} 

.someContainer {
   margin-top: 50px
}
```

attached [Pen](https://codepen.io/HiLuLiT/pen/OJXeZXB)

Comment: I agree with your approach which is simpler.  Though I would personally prefer to set the general properties first THEN override with the more specific (e.g. the first-child).  Although the above code works due to CSS specificity, overriding styles is the nature of CSS (i.e. the last of multiple equal selectors gets applied not the first).

Comment: In some cases this may be a cleaner solution. However, in other instances, it can also cause more complexity & more difficult to maintain CSS. One example is if the margin needs to match other elements,, which may not always be "0px". First you may need to find that value. More importantly, no matter the value, if it's later changed, now you have to remember to change it here too. One modification to your code that may keep those values in synch (depending on structure) is to instead use `margin: revert;`. I also prefer @alds suggestion to put the exception 2nd.

Comment: I could not get [the other Answer’s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34018456/642706) approach to work. This simple double-rule *does* work, taking advantage of the “cascading” in Cascading Style Sheets.